# Pouchdb how can I query in a for loop?

Tags: pouchdb

I have a problem about db.query in Pouchdb.  i want to query in for loop. But My query code start to run (db.query) when my for loop block finished.
My Code :

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://127.0.0.1:5984/parameterResult');
        var parameterArr=['101','102','103'];
for (var x=0;data.length-1;x++ ){ //1. for loop 
        db.query('test/newView',{include_docs:true , startkey: [     "1001",     data[x],     "2016-05-05"   ],
        endkey:  [     "1001",     data[x],     "2016-05-05"+"\u9999"   ] }).then(function (result) {
         //   debugger;
            for (var i=0;i<result.rows.length;i++) {
                data.push(result.rows[i].value[0]);
            }
        });
}
```

to conclude : in my code ,when  My first loop line finish , my db.query() starts .
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Each query response looks like it returns a promise.  Since you're doing the same thing with all of the result sets, how about using *Promise.all*?

Sample from [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(function(values) { 
  console.log(values); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
});
```

So in your case, do something like this

```
var promises = [];

for (var x=0;data.length-1;x++ ){

promises.push(db.query('test/newView',{include_docs:true , startkey: [     "1001",     data[x],     "2016-05-05"   ],
        endkey:  [     "1001",     data[x],     "2016-05-05"+"\u9999"   ] }))

}

Promises.all(promises).then(function(values){
//Do stuff
});
```

Comment: Promise.all() is indeed the correct answer here. :) You might want to try reading [We have a problem with promises](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) and in particular the section about "how do I use forEach() with promises?" You probably want to use `Promise.all()` since PouchDB's API returns promises.